# Adding where() on with() eager loading.

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a little but intricate problem here, I'll try to explain it as best I can.

**First** I have 3 models, `Course`, `Student`, and `Quiz`,

- Student and Course are in a Many to Many relationship
- Student and Quiz are in a Many to Many relationship
- Quiz and Course are in a One to Many relationship respectively

And I have this following query:

```
 $course = Course::whereSlug($slug)->first(); // Some Course

 $quizzes = $course->students()->with('quizzes'); // <-- Here lies the problem.
```

In the last sentence I want to edit this query to be something like this:

```
 $quizzes = $course->students()->with('quizzes)->where('course_id', $course->id);
```

I want to do it like that because **I want to only grab the quizzes that are related to both the `Student` model and the `Course` model.**

**To give you the full picture**, after that I loop through the `$students` variable in a vue component like this:

```
<div v-for="student in students"></div>
```

I am looping with the `Student` model Because I'm also retrieving different properties other than the quizzes.

But of course when I do it like the query up there I end up retrieving all quizzess for the all students that has a `course_id` = `$course_id`.

**Required**

I want to filter the results to get the quizzes of a student *ONLY* if they have a `course_id` of whatever the current courses's id is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `whereHas` function to do your job, something like this:

```
$quizzes = $course
        ->students()
        ->whereHas('quizzes', function($q){
            $q->where('course_id', $course->id);
        })
        ->with('quizzes)
        ->get();
```

I think if you follow the convention you should take `Quiz` model with `students` and `course` cross checked, its upto you. You can find out more on [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) Hope this resolves your problem.

Comment: Your answer had a few typos, it was close to the answer but it didn't exactly solve my problem because if a 'Student' doesn't have any 'quizzes', I get an empty collection, and I want all 'students' regardless if they have 'quizzes' attached to them or not.

Comment: Then its better to go with the student model and find out the relationship existence, You will get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Of course after I posted the question I found the answer online randomly, here it is:

```
$quizzes = $course->students()->with(['quizzes'=> function($query) use ($course) {
              $query->where('course_id', $course->id);
           }])->get();
```